# A Fix for Badly Merged Branches

Tags: git, github

Ok, so I have a developer who had a couple different branches he needed to merge into our development branch.  After merging he noticed that one branch's changes were not reflected in the development branch (after it was pushed).

I figured we could revert the development branch to before he attempted the bad merge.  We could then merge again and we could ensure the branch was correctly merged before we pushed it out.

Unfortunately with the rollbacks and everything, the development branch is now at a state where the development branch is back to it's unmerged state, however the development branch sees the two other branches as already merged.  We can do a `git diff develop..merged-branch` and see the files aren't the same.

How would I go about getting these changes implemented into the development branch?  At this point I'm not super-worried about the history, I'd just like to get these branches into development correctly (without having to create new branches and manually enter each branch's change).

Comment: Can you post the output of `git log --decorate --graph --oneline master develop branchA branchB` (list all the branches you're asking about)?

Comment: Alrighty, I finally got it working.  The way we handled some of the changes allowed us to simply `git revert` the commit that "rolled back" the merge changes.  Apparently the issue with one branch not "merging" was because it was already merged, which is separate from this issue here.  In my case `gitk` and a lot of head scratching finally worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what [Linus Torvalds has to say](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

You either need to rebase the branch to after the revert or revert the revert and merge.

Comment: I didn't actually use `git revert` to undo the merges, I actually attempted to "reset" the develop branch with what was on master (I know, not what I should have done).  `git checkout master`, `git merge --strategy=ours develop`, `git checkout develop`, `git merge master`

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer.  Readers should note, checking out your git repo with `gitk` or using the above `git log --decorate --graph --oneline` should be done to ensure you can't find a simpler solution before doing something drastic.  Such as messing up a branch beyond recognition, like I had done.